# How to get notepad++ editor and shell to work together in python?

Tags: python

I'm learning Python using the book "Learn Python the hard way", but I'm stuck in the very beginning.  How can I get my windows shell and notepad++ to work together?  When i run python on my terminal, it doesn't show the file that i saved on my notepad++ editor.

Comment: Notepad++ is for _editing your code_ and the shell is for _running your code_. How can they _work together_? You'll need a full-featured IDE then.

Answer (score 0):

As an earlier user noted, Notepad++ is your editor, but you run code from the shell.  If you want an integrated solution, you can use an IDE like IDLE (which comes with Python) or Eclipse with PyDev.

If you want to use Notepad++, the first thing to do after opening the shell is to connect to your working directory.  I.e., if you're saving your code in `C:\Temp`, then `cd C:\Temp`.  Next, do your `dir` command and you should see your files.  From here, you can execute your scripts from the shell.

Comment: Thanks a lot , that's what I was looking for . I'm very new to coding period , and the course I'm taking says not to play with IDE IE IDLE yet so I'm sticking to that .

Comment: Glad I was able to help.  Did you need some more help with this question or are you good then?

Comment: Thanks for your help , no it's still not working . I've created a file in my editor and saved it , and i'm suppose to run it on shell but i keep getting invalid syntax . I don't know what i'm doing wrong

Comment: Then everything's working correctly. Now you're on to the debugging. This is the "hard way" part of Learning Python the Hard Way. :-D If this solved the original problem, click the check mark by the answer to "accept" it. It's not required, but it lets the next person with the same question know that this answer works to resolve the issue and also earns both of us a little reputation on the site. Best of luck!